# No access token (session) upon ParseUI login with Facebook v4

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform, parseui

Using Parse UI 1.1.3 (with Parse 1.7.2) and Facebook v4, I have a problem upon login with Facebook. 
The code is very basic:

```
let loginController = PFLogInViewController()
loginController.delegate = self
loginController.fields = PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten | PFLogInFields.LogInButton | PFLogInFields.Facebook | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton | PFLogInFields.DismissButton
loginController.facebookPermissions = ["public_profile", "user_friends"]
loginController.logInView!.logo = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "icon_parse"))
self.presentViewController(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When I logging via Facebook, there is no visual error. I retrieve a Parse User `PFUser.currentUser()`, but the Facebook access token is empty `FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()`.

Is it a bug from Parse SDK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a Parse bug, now corrected in Parse 1.7.3 (but this update makes Parse Crash Reporting crash...)

Comment: We are releasing an update with a fix for Parse Crash Reporting _soon_.